# How do I get the content from a text or html file in an assets directory to be displayed?

Tags: assets

I'm looking to display/print the contents of an html or text file uploaded into assets. Not sure what parameter to access though.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file’s contents using its `getContents()` method:

```
{{ asset.getContents() }}`
```

That will HTML-encode the contents by default; if you need it to print unencoded, add the `|raw` filter. There are some big security concerns with doing that though, as the file could contain a `<script>` tag that facilitates an XSS attack.